# Setting 1 point of a scatterplot in a different color

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a scatterplot like this

```
f,ax=plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(keyByte0To255,highestCorrVector)
ax.set_title('Key: ' + hex(getIndex))
ax.set_ylabel('Correlation Value')
ax.set_xlabel('Hypothesis 0-255')
```

[image: 1]

How do i set the highest value which is 0.5 in red?

Answer (score 2):

Or with cmap :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_values = [20, 19, 16, 12, 19, 18, 22, 14]
y_values = [1, 0.91, 0.77, 0.67, 0.85, 0.78, 1.05, 0.63]

maxx = max(y_values)

marker_colors = [100 if el == maxx else 0 for el in y_values ]
plt.scatter(x_values, y_values, c=marker_colors, cmap='bwr')

plt.colorbar()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Shooting in the dark, you can re-draw the point:

```
f,ax=plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(keyByte0To255,highestCorrVector)

# find the point
idx = np.argmax(highestCorrVector)
ax.scatter(keyByte0To255[idx], highestCorrVector[idx], c='red')

ax.set_title('Key: ' + hex(getIndex))
ax.set_ylabel('Correlation Value')
ax.set_xlabel('Hypothesis 0-255')
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!